# prevent lua window from closing

Tags: lua, notepad++

I run lua script in Notepad++ using "C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua.exe" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
[image]

it works, but lua window immediatly dissapears after executing. 
I solved this problem in ugly way in the end:

```
while true do
    a=1+1
end
```

Are there more efficient methods?

Comment: Less ugly way in the end: `io.read()`

Comment: Running it from cmd would be another solution